# Extracting info out of lists inside a jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a with a jsonb column called `jsonb` that contains data in the following format.

```
{
"stuff": [
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "percent": "90.0000"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "percent": "10.0000"
    }
],
"countries": [
    {
        "name": "USA",
        "value": "30"
    },
    {
        "name": "Canada",
        "value": "25"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mexico",
        "value": "20"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ecuador",
        "value": "10"
    }
]
}
```

I am having a lot of trouble working with this data. Specifically what I want to do is find all the different values `"name"` can have in `"stuff"` as well as in `"countries"`, kind of like a `SELECT distinct`.

But my problem is that I can't seem to extract anything useful from this jsonb. My approach so far was to do
`SELECT jsonb->>'stuff' FROM table`, but this only gave me a column of type `text` which contained `[{"name": "foo","percent": "90.0000"},{"name": "bar","percent": "10.0000"}]`.

But since this is text I can't really do anything with it. I also tried `SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb) FROM table` but that returned the following Error:

```
ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object
SQL state: 22023
```

Any help with working with this format of data is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest each array separately and then create a union on the result of those two steps:

```
select c.x ->> 'name'
from the_table
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(json_column -> 'countries') as c(x)
union 
select s.x ->> 'name'
from the_table
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(json_column -> 'stuff') as s(x);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/ZEOIXF91294